# Randomly I get the error: "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: element has zero size"

Tags: python

I get the error randomly:
"selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: element has zero size"

Sometimes the loop works until iteration 50 and sometimes to iteration 10. I wonder if there is a solution for this error I get?

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
options = wb.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = wb.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options)


pages = 0
while pages < 80:
    pages = pages+1
    driver.get(f'https://www.coop.se/globalt-sok/?query=coop&category=stores&page={pages}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a pause in the loop to allow for each page to load? If there is specific element on each page you are trying to retrieve, try waiting for that element to be present on the page.

### Explict Selenium Python Wait

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Wait until the element defined by path is present, for a max of 10 seconds.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# add a valid path to a page element you are trying to retrieve
# this div appears to hold the results for "Butiker"
# found using Develop Tools / Inspect in Google Chrome
path = "//div[@class='Grid js-storesSearchResultList']"

button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, path)
    )
)
```

Comment: I added a time.sleep(5) but perhaps I need to increase the wait?